# Strange file output when using Concat in CodeSys

Tags: file, st, codesys, caa

I'm using the CAA-File library in CodeSyS to write data to a text file. When I write a string to the file it works fine, but if I combine 2 strings with CONCAT, I get a strange file output with random characters (see below). Does anyone know how to fix this? Thank you!

For example `lString = 'test'` works fine, but `lString = CONCAT('str1', 'str2')` does not.

```
PROGRAM initDataLogger
    VAR_INPUT
        lString : STRING;
    END_VAR
    VAR
        lString : STRING:= CONCAT('str1', 'str2');
        xFileStdInit:   BOOL:=FALSE;
        uiFileStdState: UINT:=0;
        sFileName:  CAA.FILENAME:= '/var/www/html/TestFile.txt';
        hFile:      CAA.HANDLE;
        szFileSize1:    CAA.SIZE := 0;
        szFileSize2:    CAA.SIZE := 0;
        filop:      FILE.Open;
        filwr:      FILE.Write;
        filcl:      FILE.Close;
        loop: INT := 0;
        fString: STRING;
    END_VAR

IF NOT xFileStdInit THEN
    filop(xExecute:=FALSE);
    filcl(xExecute:=FALSE);
    filwr(xExecute:=FALSE);
    xFileStdInit:=TRUE;
    uiFileStdState:=0;
ELSE
    CASE uiFileStdState OF
    0: (* create a new file *)
        filop.sFileName:=sFileName;
        filop.eFileMode:=FILE.MODE.MAPPD;
        filop.xExclusive:=TRUE;
        filop( xExecute:=TRUE);
        IF filop.xDone THEN
            hFile:=filop.hFile;
            uiFileStdState:=1;
        END_IF
        IF filop.xError THEN
            (* error handling*)
            ;
        END_IF
    1:(* write text in the file *)
        //fString := CONCAT('$R$L', lString);
        fString := lString;
        filwr.hFile:=hFile;
        filwr.pBuffer:=ADR(fString);
        szFileSize1:=SIZEOF(fString);
        filwr.szSize:=szFileSize1;
        filwr.udiTimeOut:=100000;       (* 100ms Timeout *)
        IF GVL.logData THEN
            filwr( xExecute:=TRUE);
        END_IF
        IF filwr.xDone THEN
            uiFileStdState:=2;
            GVL.logData := FALSE;
        END_IF
        IF filwr.xError THEN
            (* error handling*)
            ;
        END_IF
    2:  (* close file  - TestFile.txt *)
        filcl.hFile:=hFile;
        filcl( xExecute:=TRUE);
        IF filcl.xDone THEN
            uiFileStdState:=3;
        END_IF
        IF filcl.xError THEN
            (* error handling*)
            ;
        END_IF
    3:  (* end of example *)
        xFileStdInit := FALSE;
    END_CASE
END_IF
```

For `lString = CONCAT('str1', 'str2')` I expect `str1str2` as output but I get this:

```
str1str2sys??v$??v??v?
?vd?n??
?v?`v??vd
?vK
?v?`v8
?v?v4??v?
```

Comment: In your example there is no `lString = CONCAT('str1', 'str2')` and even `str1` and 2 are not defined. It is hard to hep if you do not know уруку and how you use it.

Comment: I have changed it.

Comment: Did you try to write `lString` directly without assigning it to `fString`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out myself. It had to do with the string size. For example: `STRING(4)` outputs fine with a four letter word, but with a two letter word it adds two random character's.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't both pass lString as an input and at the same time declare it as a variable with an initial value. The compiler should refuse to build the program in that form, so either your current program is a little different than your example above, or your compiler is not doing as it should and all bets are off.

Also, I note that your program will probably stay in case 1 for more than one scan, while the file is written. Are you sure the lString input is valid or the expected value while this goes on? Can you single-step the program to confirm that?
You might want to divide first and second part of case 1 into 2 case steps or change the first part to something à la the following:

```
IF NOT filwr.xExecute THEN
    //fString := CONCAT('$R$L', lString);
    fString := lString;
    filwr.hFile:=hFile;
    filwr.pBuffer:=ADR(fString);
    szFileSize1:=SIZEOF(fString);
    filwr.szSize:=szFileSize1;
    filwr.udiTimeOut:=100000;       (* 100ms Timeout *)
END_IF
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
szFileSize1:=LEN(fString);
```

instead of

```
szFileSize1:=SIZEOF(fString);
```